# How to structure the inheritance from generic tree to a-b tree

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, tree, hierarchy

I am trying to implement an a-b tree, as a derived class from a generic tree.
The generic tree node is as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct TreeNode
{
    T value;
    std::vector<TreeNode*> children;
    //Some other trivial stuff
};
```

The structure of the a-b node is as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct ABTreeNode : TreeNode<T>
{
    std::vector<T> keys;
    //The idea is to omit the T value field of the base node and use that vector for the keys
};
```

Also in the generic tree class there exists a root field

```
TreeNode *root;
```

And the a-b constructor is

```
template<Typename T>
ABTree<T>::ABTree(T value)
{
    GenericTree<T>::root = new ABTreeNode;
    root->keys.push_back(value);
}
```

Now, the way this is made, I need to use down casting in a lot of the a-b tree methods, for example:

```
template<typename T>
bool ABTree<T>::search(T value)
{
    ABTreeNode *node = GenericTree<T>::root;
    //....
}//Downcast base to derived
```

As far as I know down casting is a bad practice and indicates bad design. The fact that I use variables defined in the derived struct but declare the node as base struct seems very error prone. What would happen if that node was created as a base node and not derived?
Eg:

```
//Somewhere:
TreeNode *node = new TreeNode;//Instead of new ABTreeNode
//..
//Somewhere else
node->keys//Shouldn't that be an error?
```

Is my approach correct? If not how should I structure it better?
PS: spare the raw pointers please.

Comment: If you want to remove some data member of the base class, don't inherit from that base class.

Comment: So there is no way to use inheritance in this case? Or at worst should I put the keys vector in the base struct?

Comment: Why do you need inheritance at all? How should `ABTreeNode` look like without inheritance? By the way, downcasts are not that bad if you know what you're doing. For example, `std::list` implementations are full of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing code by inheritance is a bad design. Better is to use Composition - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

To share code between different implementations of various trees I would extract common fields into a struct.

```
template <class T, class ChildT>
struct TreeNodeCommons
{
  T nodeValue;
  std::vector<ChildT*> children;
  // more common fields
}
```

Then I would attach it to Nodes of different types.

```
template<typename T>
struct ABTreeNode
{
  TreeNodeCommons<T, ABTreeNode<T>> commons;
  std::vector<T> keys;  
};
```

You may then write templated algorithms assuming Node contains field named *commons* and you may write Node specific algorithms as well. And there is no *dynamic_casts*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is probably what I will do. One thing though, if sharing code by inheritance is bad then when should I use it?

Comment: If you have two implementations of the same interface (mostly - one mocked for tests, one real for product). If you want to have *pimpl* idiom. From practical point of view almost all cases when I use inheritance is: pure virtual base class with no members (just methods with =0) and implementation classes.

Comment: I don't understand why it is bad design. This is how a [typical `std::list` node](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/forward_list.h#L54) is defined: `struct Node_base { Node_base* next; }; template<class T> struct Node : Node_base { T data; };`. Is it bad design?

Comment: @Evg good point. Looking at std::list I think they separated Node and Node_base so Node_base does not contain any templated attributes. This saves class size during instantiation. I think this is the case when performance is more important than having most beautify design.